# How can either convert a string into a hash or add it into a hash

Tags: ruby, methods, hash, split

So in basic Ruby I am trying to figure out how to either convert a string into a hash or put a string into a hash. I want the `pokemon` item as the key and a integer for the value.

Something like this:

```
hash = {}
pokemon_list = "pikachu charizard jigglypuff bulbasaur"

def create_poke_list(string)
  hash << string.split
end
create_poke_list
```

Expected output:

```
 hash
 #=> {"pikachu"=>0, "charizard"=>0, "jigglypuff"=>0, "bulbasaur"=>0}
```

Comment: What result do you expect for `"pikachu charizard jigglypuff bulbasaur"` string?

Comment: Please edit your question to show your desired return value (hash) for the given string `pokemon_list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pokemon_list.split.product([0]).to_h
  #=> {"pikachu"=>0, "charizard"=>0, "jigglypuff"=>0, "bulbasaur"=>0}
```

The steps:

```
a = pokemon_list.split
  #=> ["pikachu", "charizard", "jigglypuff", "bulbasaur"]
b = a.product([0])
  #=> [["pikachu", 0], ["charizard", 0], ["jigglypuff", 0], ["bulbasaur", 0]]
b.to_h
  #=> <hash shown above>
```

Alternatively,

```
Hash[pokemon_list.split.product([0])]
```

Here [Array#product](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-product) is just a short-hand form of `pokeman_list.zip(a)` where `a` is an array consisting of `pokenman_list.size` equal elements, here zero. See [Enumerable#zip](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-zip) also.

*Or use [String#gsub](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-gsub)!*

This is another way that does not require the string to be converted to an array.

```
pokemon_list.gsub(/[[:alpha:]]+/).with_object({}) { |w,h| h[w] = 0 }
  #=> {"pikachu"=>0, "charizard"=>0, "jigglypuff"=>0, "bulbasaur"=>0}
```

This works because `gsub` returns an enumerator when executed without a block. It's admittedly an unusual use of that method (since it does not replace in characters in the string), but one that I've found useful at times.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, but it needs an explanation of why #product makes more sense than `Hash.new(0)`. You and I know why it works, but #product is sort of a non-intuitive choice for most people. :)

Comment: @CodeGnome, thanks for the suggestion. I did an edit, though I don't see how `Hash.new(0)` could be used to advantage.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a hash that is initialised with default value of 0, you could simply do

```
hash = Hash.new(0)
p hash["pikachu"]
#=> 0
```